# Selecting a point and auto selecting a polygon in another layer in QGIS 3.14

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, point, features

I'm using QGIS 3.14 Pi and here's my scenario.  I have a layer of points and each points contain a numerical value `code`, let's say it's `123`.  There may be multiple points with the same `code` value.  In another layer, I have polygons, each with a unique `code`.  What I want to do is select (click on) a point and have the polygon in another layer with the matching code value select also.  The points may or may not be inside the polygon.

Many years ago in MapInfo I had an MBX that would do this, so I imagine there's a QGIS plugin that would do the same, I just don't know what to call it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know there is a plugin for that, but you can use the following script. Change the layer names and run the script in [QGIS Python Editor](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/python_console.html#the-code-editor).

```py
point_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("POINT_LAYER_NAME")[0]
polygon_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("POLYGON_LAYER_NAME")[0]

def select_related_polygon(selectedIds, deselected, clearAndSelect):
    if selectedIds:
        ID = selectedIds[0] # selected point id
        selected_point = point_lyr.getFeature(ID)
        
        expression = "code = " + str(selected_point["code"])
        polygon_lyr.selectByExpression(expression)

point_lyr.selectionChanged.connect(select_related_polygon)
```

The script works for just one selected point or the first point in `selectedIds` list.